# Solving the functional equation $ T (n) = 3 ~ T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^{2} $.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I’m trying to solve the following recurrence relations for run-time $ T(n) $. Assuming $ T(n) $ is constant for $ n \leq 2 $, solve
$$
T(n) = 3 ~ T \! \left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + n^{2}.
$$

Comment: What if $n$ is odd? How will you deal with the $T(\frac n 2)$?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX A way to put some rigor into this is to note that $$3^{-n}T(2^n)=3^{-(n-1)}T(2^{n-1})+(4/3)^n$$ hence $$T(2^n)=3^n\left(T(1)+\sum_{k=1}^n(4/3)^k\right)=3^nT(1)+4(4^n-3^n)$$ from which $$T(2^n)=\Theta(4^n)$$ follows. But yes, you are right that there is no rigorous way to pass from this to $$T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$$ although this is what the authors of the question have in mind. That's life...

Comment: @AlgorithmsX 0). The actual recurrence relation ought to have floors and/or ceilings. 1). Prove (or have it by assumptions) that $T$ is monotone. 2). Deal with inputs of the form $2^k$. 3. Deal with general $n$ by squeezing between some $2^k \leq n < 2^{k+1}$. 4. Show that the squeezing is alright, as the solution obtained for $T$ does not grow insanely fast. 5. Conclude. 6. Forget all the above ever happened, because you do not have time to remember this -- hey, it's only a class one *has* to take to graduate, why bother with subtleties anyway?

Comment: It's interesting that there are other questions with the same context, posted on the same day! Such as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1950879

Comment: @polfosol Not that surprising. Algorithms classes starting in Fall 2016 are having their first or second homeworks around that time of year...

Comment: @ClementC.  Struggling out here trying my best, got stuck on these

Comment: "trying my best" Such as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real $n$ there are exact solutions $A|n|^b + cn^2$ where $A$ is a free parameter and $b,c$ are determined by the recurrence.  The recurrence for integer $n$ will approximate that after defining what $T(n/2)$ means.

The exponent $b$ is the same as the fractional dimension of the Sierpinski triangle which is made of $3$ copies of itself at $1/2$ the scale, a form of the same recurrence (without the $n^2$ term).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this asymptotics, note that this fits the form of the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), which gives conditions to determine the asymptotic growth of $$T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n).$$

In this case, $a=3, b=2, f(n)=n^2$ and $\log_2 3 = 1.58$. Thus, by the master theorem, since $2 > 1.58$ and $3\cdot(n/2)^2 = (3/4)\cdot n^2 \leq (3/4) n^2$, we have $T(n) = \Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: I have somewhat the feeling that if the OP didn't think immediately of that theorem, (s)he must not have seen it already. (The Master theorem is *not*, from experience, something students forget to invoke -- whether it applies or not.)

Comment: @ClementC. - Maybe. Students don't always pay attention or go to class.

Comment: True (incidentally, I did not downvote, although I do think that the Master theorem is a convenient shortcut/method only once that people know how to deal with these recurrences without it.)

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that by setting $T(n)=4n^2+S(n)$ the original recurrence boils down to something simpler, namely

$$ S(n) =3\cdot S(n/2) $$
admitting the solution $S(n) = n^\alpha$, with $\alpha = \log_2(3)$, such that
$$ T(n) = 4n^2 + n^{1.5849625\ldots} $$
is a solution of the original recurrence, that I think may come from the study of [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) complexity.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{T}\pars{n} = 3\,\mrm{T}\pars{n \over 2} + n^{2}:\ ?\,,\qquad
> \left.\vphantom{\large A}\mrm{T}\pars{n}\right\vert_{\ n\ \leq\ 2} = \mbox{'initial' constant}}$.

Lets $\ds{\,\mrm{T}\pars{n} \equiv \tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n}n^{2}\implies
\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n} = {3 \over 4}\,\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n \over 2} + 1
\implies\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n} - 4 =
{3 \over 4}\bracks{\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n \over 2} - 4}}$ which leads to:
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n} - 4 & =
{3 \over 4}\,{3 \over 4}\bracks{\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n \over 2^{2}} - 4} =
{3 \over 4}\,{3 \over 4}\,{3 \over 4}
\bracks{\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n \over 2^{3}} - 4} = \cdots =
\pars{3 \over 4}^{k}
\bracks{\tilde{\mrm{T}}\pars{n \over 2^{k}} - 4}
\end{align}
which is equivalente to
$$
\mrm{T}\pars{n} = 4n^{2} +
\pars{3 \over 4}^{k}n^{2}
\bracks{{\mrm{T}\pars{n/2^{k}} \over \pars{n/2^{k}}^{2}} - 4}
$$

---

$$\bbox[8px,#efe,border:0.1em groove navy]{%
\mrm{T}\pars{n} = 4n^{2} +
\pars{3 \over 4}^{k}
\bracks{2^{2k}\,\mrm{T}\pars{n \over 2^{k}} - 4n^{2}}}
$$

> The final solution is found with a value of $\ds{k}$ which satisfies
>   $\ds{{n \over 2^{k}} \leq 2 \implies k \geq {\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{2}} - 1}$

$$\bbox[8px,#efe,border:0.1em groove navy]{%
\mrm{T}\pars{n} = 4n^{2} +
\pars{3 \over 4}^{k_{c}}
\bracks{2^{2k_{c}}\,\mrm{T}\pars{n \over 2^{k_{c}}} - 4n^{2}}}\,,\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{k_{c}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{\left\lceil{\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{2}} - 1\right\rceil}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{T}\pars{n \over 2^{k_{c}}}} & \ds{=} & \mbox{'initial' constant}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: I like the fanciful boxes.

Comment: @Transcendental It's allowed by the [MSE-MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22395/85343).